# How can I use deep watcher over array of objects in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, rendering, watch, nuxtjs3

I am working on nuxt 3 project and I need to manage the trigger on the change of specific object items from array.

I have a one child form component and I am receiving props `formData: { type: Object },`.

**Example of props.formData**

```js
const formData = reactive({
   data: [
    {
      type: "",
      name: "",
      exist: false,
    },
    {
      type: "",
      name: "",
      exist: true,
    },
  ],
})
```

Now, I need to keep watch if formData has new item (on changing the length of formData) OR only if the objects `exist` property value changes not any other (name or type)

I have tried deep watch but it is triggering if any single change is occurred

Please help me with this if there is a valid fix available

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why is it important, that no update is triggered on type or name changes? Some context makes answering easier.

Comment: @FelixDolderer Just for the performance enhancing. If there is no way I can set the nested conditions under the deep watch